# iPhone IBOutlet

Tags: iphone, ipad

What is IBOutlet in iOS from a newbie point of view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find solution to your doubt here [IBOutlet and IBAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction)

Answer (score 0):

Macros that allow you to connect properties to the Interface Builder.
[IBOutlet](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitConstantsReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/IBOutlet)