# iOS 4 - How to add table view to a tab bar application

Tags: iphone

I am new to iPhone programming and am having a really hard time trying to figure out how to add a table view to a tab bar application. There are not many tutorials on this for iOS SDK 4 and the Apple documentation is very light on details. Since I am new I would really like some tutorial that has screenshots (or at least clear instructions) when it comes to things being done in Interface Builder (like making connections between the objects and File Owner, etc), usually lot of tutorials/blogs gloss out these details.
What I am trying to do is create a tab bar based application with 3 tabs (this I am able to do). The first tab needs to display a table view with the header having 2 buttons (one on right and other on left, with the title in middle).The title is actually today's date, obtained from the phone. Clicking either of the header buttons should take you to another table and the title should be yesterday's date (if left button is clicked) and tomorrow's date if right button is clicked.
Can some one please suggest me a good tutorial for this. I am thoroughly confused by the Interface Builder (especially how to create connections).

Comment: I personally hate interface builder.  I think it slows down development time, and it can be a pain to work.  I'm sure others will disagree with me on this, but why don't you try programmatically handling view elements?  Its much easier to conceptualize.

Comment: What goes into the table view? You seem to be describing the UI navigation bar at the top which can control any view including a table view. The links between Interface Builder and code are the IBOutlet and IBAction keywords: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction. This tutorial might be helpful: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk-interface-builder-basic-training/.

Comment: Hi Dave, The table view will display items from an array, events from the iPhone calendar to be exact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only page I remember frequenting on the past, is [CocoaDevCentral](http://cocoadevcentral.com/).

Personally, I learnt how to use Xcode through video tutorials, so I recommend you to start searching there. Also, to help you with your search, always look for the full name of the objects involved, for example: instead of searching for "*tableView*", look for "*UITableView*", apple's notation is very particular and helps narrowing down the result.

Finally, ignore the nay-sayers about Interface Builder, you should give it a try, and see if it fits your style. For instance, I like being able to get a look at the overall design, as I usually help with the design.

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to get this working finally. Here is a good tutorial, if someone is interested - http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/rss-reader-part-4-setting-up-the-uitabbar-and-uitableview-with-delegates/