# IBOutlet confusion

Tags: objective-c, iboutlet

I'm going through some confusion phase after moving from Java/Android to iOS/Objective-C and can't understand or find any viable explanation on the following:

- What is IBOutlet?
- What use does it have?
- Does IBoutlet code have to be defined in each implementation file or
  header file?

Any similiar stuff to what we have in java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBOutlet and IBAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction)

Comment: Just a note on future reference for people finding this through google on comparison yes R.java file equates to Outlet / action. Having reviewed the Stanford university video the simplest definition. what is Outlet: Lets Controller talk to View. what is Action: Lets View talk to controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are experienced in Android I am sure you have used the resources file to reference subviews like buttons or image views of a certain .xml-view within your projects.

For example:

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myimageview);
```

While this properties will automatically by linked to the resources file in Android, this will not be done for your iOS projects. Instead you link subviews directly to the dedicated .h-file by create a new IBOutlet property and link it via the Interface Builder.

Same for IBAction. While you can reference a button directly and add an onClick listener via

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);
```

to receive the action in the onClick methode of "this", this is different in your iOS project. Again, you link the action which will be triggered by the button directly to the dedicated .h-file and mark the action coming from XIB-file with IBAction (see answer by alex).
As stated by Mark Adams, IBOutlet and IBAction is nothing more than a void typedef and will only be used by compiler.

Comment: Intresting explanation thing which i took for granted as R.java doesnt get given by iOS well surely apple can do this as auto run like google do when you modify layout.xml or manifest file. Thx for comparison makes a lot sense.

i would also say here that when we talking about interface bulider we meant storyboard.

Answer (score 4):

**IBOutlet**

Say you added a UILabel to your .xib Interface file and you e.g. want to change the text of the label later on during runtime, you'd have to reference it somehow.
By adding the IBOutlet keyword you basically tell your .xib-file that you want to connect an existing UILabel to this property.
Interface Builder will recognize, and gives you the possibility to wire up the label to your code.

```
@property (unsafe_unretained, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
```

However, if you never want to change the Label after it was initialized from the .xib, you don't have to create a property anyway.

**IBAction**

The same thing would apply to functions on a UIButton.
E.g. if you added a button in your .xib-file and want to trigger a function on the button clicked event, you'd declare your function like this.

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender;
```

Again, the IBAction keyword simply tells Interface Builder that you'd like to wire this function to anything inside the .xib-file (in our case the button).

Btw, nothing happens by simply declaring something as IBOutlet or IBAction. You'd always have to go back into Interface Builder and wire everything up as desired.

Comment: Don't be thrown by the IBAction return type either. IBAction is typedef'd to void.

Comment: @alex thx for the clear explanation i would have accepted your answer too but stackoverflow wont allow two answers. i found both yours and markus answer to be very handy.

Answer (score 1):

The IBOutlet is just a "heads up" for the compiler to be able to create links between .xib files and header files. It is similar to void, but needed to create the connections to any interface builder file

Answer (score 0):

**IBOutlet**: If you declare a variable as `IBOutlet` you are putting that variable in the Outlet of the class in Interface Builder. In other words you have the chance for connect that variable to a component (with the same class, of course) using the Interface Builder (from now IB).

There is another special word for IB: **IBAction**. If you declare the return type of a method as `IBAction`, you are putting that method as action that can be assinged by Interface Builder to a button touch up or other actions. There is not nescessary to return any special value, just assume that return value is void.

If you are new in iOS, just an advice: be careful using the Interface Builder because all variables that must be instantiated by Interface Builder (like a custom UILabel or what ever) will be intantiathed with the method initWithCoder instead of init or initWithNibName. I did loose a lot of time with that!

I hope it helped.