# Use void instead IBAction as return type of method

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm studying ObjC and iOS development. Every components that I use in my apps are created programmatically (views, button, labels, etc).

Here is my code

```
...
UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
[self.btn addTarget:self 
                  action:@selector(someAction:) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
....


-(void)someAction
{
 logic
}
```

I notice that I can use void instead of IBAction as return type of selector. Is this the correct approach ?
Could there be any pitfalls ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [IBOutlet and IBAction](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Using `IBAction` tells Xcode that you want the method to be available as an action method in Interface Builder.  That's the only effect.  Otherwise it is identical to `void`.  In fact in `UINibDeclarations.h` you will find this:

```
#define IBAction void
```

Using `IBAction` is a good idea even if you don't use nib files, because it is a signal to the reader (you or a coworker) that you intended to use the method as the action of a UI control.

Comment: Not to open a new topic. I prefer to create everything programmatically rather using IB. Maybe sounds crazy, but that approach is easiest for me. Are they any cons of using that approach ?

Comment: Yes, there are cons. Using or not using IB tends to be a religious argument.  I use it heavily.  Most of the sample apps from Apple use it.  I assume that people who don't use it like to write a lot of boilerplate code and go through many edit-compile-run cycles tweaking view coordinates, colors, and font sizes in their code.

Comment: In Xcode's editor, there's a small icon to indicate whether it's connected or not. Using IBAction/IBOutlet for non-IB method/property may be confusing. But anyway, it's a matter of taste.