# can I use below method as an IBAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder, uipageviewcontroller

can I use below function as an IBAction - on a button click ? if YES then please tell me how...

```
-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController
      viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController

-(UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController 
     viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't.

`IBAction` is actually equal to `void` -> only void returning methods can be connected.

http://cocoadev.com/wiki/IBAction
[IBOutlet and IBAction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction)

Also the methods you are referring to are implementing the [UIPageViewControllerDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html), therefore a UIPageViewController should call them, but never you, see [Delegates and Data Sources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18).

Comment: so you mean that I can not call these functions programmatically ?

Comment: So create a new question (after searching of course), where you ask about jumping between pages of an UIPageViewController — I never used one.

Comment: actually you did that. you should retag that, as xcode is not a valid tag for that question. It is just an IDE. you could also write apps using vi and the commandline