# Resize a UITextField while typing (by using Autolayout)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, autolayout

I have a UITableViewCell which has two UITextFields (without borders). The following constraints are used to set up the horizontal layout.

`@"|-10-[leftTextField(>=80)]-(>=10)-[rightTextField(>=40)]-10-|"`

Nothing fancy, and works as expected.

[image]

As you can see the upper textField has the correct size. The lower textField started with an empty text, and because of the empty text it is 80 points wide. When I type text into the editing textField the text scrolls to the left, it does not change its width.

I don't like that, the width of the textField should adjust while the user types into that textField.

In my opinion that should work out of the box. By implementing a `IBAction` for the `UIControlEventEditingChanged` event I can confirm that typing actually changes the `intrinsicContentSize` of the UITextField.

But well, the width does not change until the textField is no longer the first responder. If I put the cursor into another textField the width of the edited textField is set. That's a bit late for what I want.

These commented out lines is what I tried without any success:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
//        [self.contentView removeConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
//        [self.contentView addConstraints:horizontalConstraints];
//        [self.contentView layoutIfNeeded];

//        [self.contentView setNeedsLayout];

//        [self.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(textField.intrinsicContentSize));
}
```

Does anybody know what I am missing? What could I try to make this work?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is what works for me:

```
- (IBAction) textFieldDidChange: (UITextField*) textField
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [textField invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }];
}
```

What's interesting is that it seems as if it SHOULD work out of the box, given this [text from the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/dividingResponsibility.html):

> In addition, if a property of a view changes and that change affects
>   the intrinsic content size, the view must call
>   invalidateIntrinsicContentSize so that the layout system notices the
>   change and can re-layout. In the implementation of your view class,
>   you must ensure that if the value of any property upon which the
>   intrinsic size depends changes, you invoke
>   invalidateIntrinsicContentSize. **For example, a text field calls
>   invalidateIntrinsicContentSize if the string value changes.**

My best guess is that the textfield only calls invalidateIntrinsicContentSize once editing has finished, not during.

**Edit:**  A bunch of "This is not working for me".   I think the confusion here is perhaps the triggering event that is tied to the `textFieldDidChange:` handler.   The event needs to be UIControlEventEditingChanged.  If you're using IB, double check that you're handling the right event.

The `UITextField` also cannot be constrained in size.  You can lock it into position with constraints, but any width constraint, or set of left+right positioning constraints will prevent it from resizing to its intrinsic content size.

Comment: This is not working for me. The intrinsic content size does not appear to change when typing in a text field until it resigns first responder, regardless of calling `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize`

Comment: This *almost* works for me. I detailed the issues I am seeing in a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22106426/resize-uitextfield-horizontally-with-text-using-auto-layout

Comment: One thing to note is that textFieldDidChange: is NOT called if you change the contents of the text field programmatically, i.e. `[textField setText:@"Hello World"];`

Comment: Shouldn't the return be void? Why IBAction?

Answer (score 20):

I don't know why `UITextField` only updates its `intrinsicContentSize` when it resigns its first responder status. This happens for both iOS 7 and iOS 8.

As a temporary solution, I override `intrinsicContentSize` and determine the size using `typingAttributes`. This accounts for `leftView` and `rightView` as well

```
// This method is target-action for UIControlEventEditingChanged
func textFieldEditingChanged(textField: UITextField) {
  textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}


override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    if isEditing {
      let string = (text ?? "") as NSString
      let size = string.size(attributes: typingAttributes)
      return CGSize(width: size.width + (rightView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0) + (leftView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0) + 2,
                    height: size.height)
    }

    return super.intrinsicContentSize
  }
```

Here I make the it wider to account for the caret

Comment: Great. Thanks. This should be the right answer (at least for iOS7/8)

Comment: Thanks worked for me. One thing I've added is check in the 'if' statement self.text.length > 0 so the content size is correct in case there is a hint set (placeholder filed)

Comment: what would this look like in swift 3?

Comment: let string = text ?? placeholder ?? "" // checked placeholder

Comment: Doesn't seem to calculate enough width, unfortunately.

Answer (score 4):

Here's the answer in Swift. As a bonus, this snippet doesn't collapse the text field if there is a placeholder.

```
// UITextField subclass

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldTextDidChange), forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
}

func textFieldTextDidChange(textField: UITextField) {
    textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}

override func intrinsicContentSize() -> CGSize {
    if self.editing {
        let textSize: CGSize = NSString(string: ((text ?? "" == "") ? self.placeholder : self.text) ?? "").sizeWithAttributes(self.typingAttributes)
        return CGSize(width: textSize.width + (self.leftView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0) + (self.rightView?.bounds.size.width ?? 0) + 2, height: textSize.height)
    } else {
        return super.intrinsicContentSize()
    }
}
```

Comment: This works pretty well, but it breaks when you hold the backspace button until it deletes entire words.

Answer (score 3):

**First things first**: in Swift 4, UITextField's intrinsicContentSize is a computed variable, not a method.

Below is a Swift4 solution with a specialized use case. A right justified textfield can resize and extend leftward up to a certain pixel boundary.
The textfield is assigned to the **CurrencyTextField class** which inherits from **UITextField**. CurrencyTextField is then extended to provide custom behavior for returning the object's **intrinsicContentSize**, a computed variable.
.
The "**editing changed**" event of the CurrencyTextField instance is mapped to the **repositionAndResize IBAction method** in its host UIViewController class. This method simply invalidates the current intrinsic content size of the CurrencyTextField instance. Invoking the CurrencyTextField's **invalidateIntrinsicContentSize** method ( inherited form UITextField ) triggers an attempt to get the object's intrinsic content size.

The custom logic in CurrencyTextField's intrinsicContentSize getter method has to convert the CurrentTextField's text property to NSString in order ascertain its size, which it returns as the intrinsicContentSize if the x coordinate of the CurrencyTextField is greater than the stipulated pixel boundary.

```
class CurrencyTextField:UITextField {

}

extension CurrencyTextField {


     override open var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {

        if isEditing {
            let string = (text ?? "") as NSString
            let stringSize:CGSize = string.size(withAttributes: 
             [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 
             19.0)])
             if self.frame.minX > 71.0 {
                return stringSize
             }
       }

       return super.intrinsicContentSize
    }


}

class TestController: UIViewController {

    @IBAction func repositionAndResize(_ sender: CurrencyTextField) {
        sender.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar requirement with a `UITextView` (had to dynamically increase it's height and some other things).

What I did was something similar to this:

Considering  `self.contentView` is the `superview` of `textField`

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    //You can also use "textField.superview" instead of "self.contentView"
    [self.contentView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];

    //Since you wish to animate that expansion right away...
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations:^{
        [self.contentView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
    }];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGSize(textField.intrinsicContentSize));
}
```

Also, considering the requirements I had, I had to override the `updateConstraints` method of my `UITextView`'s `superview`.

Should you choose to opt for that solution (maybe for a more fine tuned approach), you can do:

```
- (void)updateConstraints {
    [super updateConstraints];

    //Firstly, remove the width constraint from the textField.
    [self.myTextField removeConstraint:self.textFieldWidthConstraint];
    self.textFieldWidthConstraint = nil;

    CGSize contentSize = self.myTextField.intrinsicContentSize;
    self.textFieldWidthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.myTextField attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationGreaterThanOrEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1 constant:contentSize.width];

    [self.myTextField addConstraint:self.textFieldWidthConstraint];
}
```

As mentioned, the override option was used by me because I required a more fine tuned approach.

Additionally, as always you'll need to make sure that you're checking for any edge cases (in terms of sizing values) that you think you might encounter.

Hope this helps!

Cheers!

Comment: Why is this an IBAction and not a delegate method that returns void?

Comment: And why does your method say TextField if what you need is TextView?

Comment: @KatedralPillon IBAction resolves to void. It's a way of showing that it resolves to a connection in Interface Builder. Refer to this post for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643007/iboutlet-and-ibaction

Comment: Regarding TextField v/s TextView - the original question was apropos a TextField, which is why the sample code that I gave had to do with a UITextField.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, calling `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` wasn't working for me either, but I also ran into issues with the other solutions due to the margins and editing controls.

This solution isn't always needed; if `invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` works, then all that needs to be done is to add a call to that when the text is changed, as in the other answers. If that isn't working, then here's a solution (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41580217/1317564)) I found which also works with a clear control:

```
class AutoResizingUITextField: UITextField {
    var lastTextBeforeEditing: String?

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        setupTextChangeNotification()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        setupTextChangeNotification()
    }                

    func setupTextChangeNotification() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: Notification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidChange,
            object: self,
            queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in                   
                self.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            forName: Notification.Name.UITextFieldTextDidBeginEditing,
            object: self,
            queue: OperationQueue.main) { (notification) in
                self.lastTextBeforeEditing = self.text
        }
    }                

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = super.intrinsicContentSize

        if isEditing, let text = text, let lastTextBeforeEditing = lastTextBeforeEditing {
            let string = text as NSString
            let stringSize = string.size(attributes: typingAttributes)
            let origSize = (lastTextBeforeEditing as NSString).size(attributes: typingAttributes)
            size.width = size.width + (stringSize.width - origSize.width)
        }

        return size
    }

    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```

If [`invalidateIntrinsicContentSize` is working by itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41602156/1317564), this will end up double-counting the change so that needs to be checked first.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is to set leading/trailing constraints to the textField and use `isActive` to turn them on/off.

When editing start, turn them on, if the text is centered, the effect will be the same (text will seems to be auto resizing as typing). When editing stops, turn constraints off, which will wrap the frame around the text.

Answer (score 0):

For me i also added a target to the textfield (UIControlEventEditingChanged)

```
- (void)textFieldChanged:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField sizeToFit];
}
```

if you have a background color, then just update it in delegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    textField.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in viewDidLoad to solve the problem.

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)])
{
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
```