# Resize UITextField horizontally with text using Auto Layout

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios7, uitextfield, autolayout

An example project to demonstrate the below issue can be found here: https://github.com/markdorison/UITextFieldContentSizeExample/

I am attempting to have a UITextField grow/shrink its width with the text content it contains using Auto Layout. I have created leading and trailing constraints with a priority of 749 (as opposed to the default: 1000). I have also tried lowering the priority of these constraints all the way down to 1, but this does not seem to have a noticeable effect on the behavior.

[image: constraints screenshot]

By listening to the UIControlEventEditingChanged event, I am triggering a reset of the intrinsicContentSize:

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)textField {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1 animations: ^{
        [textField invalidateIntrinsicContentSize];
    }];
}
```

This approach *almost* works. There are two issues:

1. I am setting a placeholder. However wide the placeholder is, the width of the UITextField's intrinsicContentSize will never drop below it. So if the placeholder's width is 130, and I begin to type, the text view's width will remain at 130 until what I am typing reaches a width greater than 130; after this the text view will grow.
2. In my example I have placed a UITextView below the UITextField. When I type in the UITextField, its width grows as expected. I can then tap into the UITextView and edit the text. If I then go back and edit the UITextView, its width no longer grows/shrinks as expected. The values being returned by the UITextField's intrinsicContentSize property go from being standard-looking integers like `{192, 28}`, to `{191.536, 27.959999}`.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've found that for issue 2 the UITextField only resizes properly when it was empty on focus. If there is any text already in the field, instrinsicContentSize doesn't change at all on UIControlEventEditingChanged.

Comment: @ChristopherCamps You've just saved me a couple of hours. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: @Rudolf Adamkovic, how did you solve it?

Answer (score 6):

> I am setting a placeholder. However wide the placeholder is, the width of the UITextField's intrinsicContentSize will never drop below it. So if the placeholder's width is 130, and I begin to type, the text view's width will remain at 130 until what I am typing reaches a width greater than 130; after this the text view will grow.

I think you'll have to use a UITextField subclass where *you* get to set the `instrinsicContentSize`, overriding the default behavior of the `intrinsicContentSize` method which is evidently to size based on the placeholder.

Comment: This has been the best/only solution I've found. Specifically overriding `intrinsicContentSize` with `return self.isEditing ? [super.text sizeWithAttributes:self.typingAttributes] : [super intrinsicContentSize];`

Comment: How would I do this for UITextView? There seems to be no `intrinsicContentSize` method.

Comment: @KatedralPillon Pls do not hijack via comments. If you have a question, _ask_ it as a _question_.

Comment: I just asked a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28129799/resize-uitextview-vertically-with-text-using-autolayout