# Narrowing Down UITextField on BackSpace while typing

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Using Storyboard, I setup a UITextField and two static UILabels. I setup the constraints so the static labels spread out as user types in the TextField.

```
       [Label1] [TextField] [Label2]

[Label1] [TextFieldIsGettingFilled] [Label2]
```

Everything is fine until now. The TextField is getting wider as user types in. However, if the user uses backspace (deletes character), TextField doesn't get narrower. So it becomes like:

```
[Label1] [TextField         ] [Label2]
```

What is the way of detecting backspace and narrow TextFields' width accordingly while user is still typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

I made an example and this works (increases and decreases according to text):

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    return true
}
```

Source: [Resize a UITextField while typing (by using Autolayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236661/resize-a-uitextfield-while-typing-by-using-autolayout)