# Change UITextField width dynamically depends of content

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I have the same issue as here: [Resize a UITextField while typing (by using Autolayout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18236661/resize-a-uitextfield-while-typing-by-using-autolayout)

But It was resolved with `UITextView` and not with `UITextField`.

This code doesn't help:

```
func textFieldDidChange(sender: UITextField) {
    sender.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
}
```

I have `UITextField`(red background) and use AutoLayout with StackView:

[image]

and constraints:

[image]

but `UITextField` change it width only when it is `resignFirstResponder`.
Could you give me please any advice about the issue?
I'm new in Swift and iOS Development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this using Autolayout, you will need a constraint for the width of the text field. Then, when the text changes, calculate the desired width and set the `constant` property on the constraint to that value. Lastly, you will need to call `layoutIfNeeded()` on the parent view.

Answer (score 3):

`UITextField` does not call your method `textFieldDidChange(_:)` when it changes content (it is not part of `UITextFieldDelegate`). You should use `textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:)` instead.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    textField.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    return true
}
```

Comment: As this answer is correct and complete, I'm not gonna say you're wrong (cause you're not), but `UITextField` is subclass of `UIControl`... You can add a target for state `Editing Changed` (possible in code and from IB)... that's where you can detect if text changed.

Answer (score 1):

This works for UITextField.
In my case I wanted the font to be of the same size. I set textField width constraint to >= 10 and it just works fine on iOS 9, 10, 11.

For iOS 11 this even works while editing text.

To make this work while editing text on iOS 9 and 10, I handled one more method by registering for a textDidChange event.

```
//Swift 3 Sample

//In viewDidLoad
adjustableTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange(_:)), for: .editingChanged)


 @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    adjustableTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    adjustableTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```