# Is there a way to add constraints into the xcode storyboard with code?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I see that in the storyboard, under Constraints, it lists all of the constraints being used. I am currently doing video tutorials and I think it would be a lot easier to simply write down what I see instead of dragging and connecting everything right now. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Please read [Auto Layout Guide: Programmatically Creating Constraints](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html)

Comment: @vadian Yes I understand you can do it that way, but that is not what I asked for. I asked if there is a way to do it inside of the main storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The respective classes to use are 'NSLayoutConstraint' and 'NSLayoutAnchor'. It is described in the programming guide "Auto Layout Guide".

BTW:
I just found another question that actually shows some code how to use it:
[How to set UITextField width constraint to have room for a certain string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51676709/how-to-set-uitextfield-width-constraint-to-have-room-for-a-certain-string)